# for each next loop to for next loop highest number

Tags: vb.net

Sorry if this is a *really* basic question but my textbook says to modify the btnGet_Click procedure to use the For Each...Next statement rather than the For...Next statement.  I cant get it to work right, so here is the original For Each...Next loop.

```
 Private Sub btnGet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGet.Click
    ' displays the highest commission and the
    ' number who were paid that amount

    Dim intCommissions() As Integer = {2500, 3400, 1000,
                                       3400, 2500, 1000,
                                       2850, 3000, 2780, 1890}
    Dim intLastSub As Integer =
        intCommissions.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim intHighest As Integer = intCommissions(0)
    Dim intSalesPeople As Integer = 1

    For intSub As Integer = 1 To intLastSub
        If intCommissions(intSub) = intHighest Then
            intSalesPeople += 1
        Else
            If intCommissions(intSub) > intHighest Then
                intHighest = intCommissions(intSub)
                intSalesPeople = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next intSub

    lblHighest.Text = intHighest.ToString("C0")
    lblSalespeople.Text = intSalesPeople.ToString
End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your post to also show us what you've tried with `For Each ..` and tell us what is not working with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to run the for each over the `intCommissions` array:

```
    Dim intCommissions() As Integer = {2500, 3400, 1000,
                                3400, 2500, 1000,
                                2850, 3000, 2780, 1890}
    Dim intHighest As Integer = intCommissions(0)
    Dim intSalesPeople As Integer = 1

    For Each intCommission In intCommissions
        If intCommission = intHighest Then
            intSalesPeople += 1
        Else
            If intCommission > intHighest Then
                intHighest = intCommission
                intSalesPeople = 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Not what your book requires you to do, so this is not strictly an answer to your question, but if you want to give a look at Linq.....

```
Dim intHighest = intCommissions.Max()
Dim intSalesPeople = intCommissions.Where(Function(x) x = intHighest ).Count()

lblHighest.Text = intHighest.ToString("C0")
lblSalespeople.Text intSalesPeople.ToString)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim intCommissions() As Integer = {2500, 3400, 1000,
                                       3400, 2500, 1000,
                                       2850, 3000, 2780, 1890}
    Dim intLastSub As Integer =
        intCommissions.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim intHighest As Integer = intCommissions(0)
    Dim intSalesPeople As Integer = 0    ' you need set 0.

    For Each intCurrent In intCommissions
        If intCurrent = intHighest Then
            intSalesPeople += 1
        Else
            If intCurrent > intHighest Then
                intHighest = intCurrent
                intSalesPeople = 1
            End If
        End If

    Next

    Label1.Text = intHighest.ToString("C0")
    TextBox1.Text = intSalesPeople.ToString
```